# I want to Consume a URL given by twitter to obtain the JSON file?

Tags: java, json, webservice-client

How does one consume web services that return JSON data in the response?

I am trying to build an app around twitter's API (for ex: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=shivkumarganesh)

I have a Twitter URL  . Now this when queried returns a JSON file. Can you help me to identify that how can I consume this in order to retrieve the results. I want to build an application around it. Please let me koow. I am using Netbeans 7 as my IDE so if there is a tutorial for such a thing in Netbeans and that too in Java then please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a JSON web service from a Java client application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536214/using-a-json-web-service-from-a-java-client-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices here: 1. Consume the twitter API on your server 2.  Consume the API in the client

The fastest to roll out would be number 2 since you'll just fire an ajax request to the API and consume the JSON response.

Consuming it on your server(presumably a j2ee application) will require a JSON Serializer/Deserialzer. There are several available(see json.org) but I personally prefer flexjson. google-gson is also good.

Comment: I do agree that consuming at the client side would be the best. But What I am searching for is a tutorial that can show me how to do this stuff. Coz I have no experience with REST based apps neither Web Services. Can you point me to some good tutorials?? which could tell me how to consume this URL? or Consume REST based service?

Comment: please just provide a hint on how to use this url.... as in how to make a call to this URL?

Comment: For starters, if you are trying to do the client route, use jQuery. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: If you want to use Java, I suggest you use flexjson to parse the JSON response of whatever api you are trying to consume and use Apache HttpComponents to query the api. I have done this myself and it works pretty well. HttpComponents even handles https and Http authentication if needed. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You're just needing to decode the JSON, so look into Gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/